# Regex to remove everything before and including the last number in a string

Tags: regex

Here is my string:
LWS53B 03 NORTH LITTLE ROCK, AR

Here's what I want to return:
NORTH LITTLE ROCK, AR

Here's the expression I'm currently using:
.*(?=(\d+)(?!.*\d))

This pretty much gets me there, but it leaves the last '3'

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Need more details in the question

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far so that we can check where the problem could be?

Comment: A regular expression does not remove something. It matches (part of) of a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match all after the last number in the string you could match a digit followed by zero or more times a space. Then use a capturing group for your values matching not a digit or a newline one or more times until the end of the string.

`\d[ ]*([^\d\r\n]+)$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h0mdMr/1)

**Explanation**

- `\d` Match a digit
- `[ ]*` Match zero or more times a space (You could use `\s*` if you want to match zero or more times a whitespace character)
- `(` Capturing group

  - `[^\d\r\n]+` negated character class to match not a digit or a newline one or more times
- `)`
- `$` Assert end of the string

Answer (score 0):

The following regex is removes everything before number.

```
'LWS53B 03 NORTH LITTLE ROCK, AR'.replace(/(.*)([0-9]+)(.*)/g, '$3')
```